# unable to cast object of type 'system.data.datarow' to type 'system.data.datarowview'

Tags: vb.net

I keep receiving

> unable to cast object of type 'system.data.datarow' to type
>   'system.data.datarowview'

for this first line of code it doesn't even get to the 2nd line can someone please advise I have googled and searched but none of the examples I have found are in the language I am using which is no help to me.

```
    For Each lDataRow As DataRow In Me.SearchGrid.SelectedItems
        lDataRow.Delete()
        lDataTable = lDataRow.Table
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your grid is bound to a dataview, not a data table.  In order to iterate the rows, you have to do

```
For Each lDataRow As DataRowView In Me.SearchGrid.SelectedItems
```

But remember, this is just the view, not the table.  So you are probably better getting the identifier from the row and then going back to the table and deleting the value there and then updating the dataview to reflect the changes.

Comment: I tried that too and when I changed it, it didn't like lDataRow.Table and I couldn't figure out after that how to make it work the options I had didn't make it work either, I am a C# programmer and I just started this new job and they do VB and though it's the same concept certain things are way different.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the selected rows, you have to ask for the selected rows and not the selected items:

```
For Each test As DataRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
    test.Delete()
Next
```

The above code runs just fine for me.

Comment: I don't have .SelectedRows as an option I only have .SelectedItem or .SelectedItems